# Heroku not serving files from assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I'm trying out Heroku as a host for our current Rails 4.0.0 project. Although this seems to be a regular issue for Heroku users, none of the solutions that I have found have made any difference for me.

The server is not serving up any of our images, css, or js from our assets.

I've tried adding gems:

```
gem 'rails_log_stdout',           github: 'heroku/rails_log_stdout'
gem 'rails3_serve_static_assets', github: 'heroku/rails3_serve_static_assets'
gem 'rails_12factor'
```

and setting the config options in `production.rb` to:

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Accel-Redirect"
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

in various combinations but the server still will not load any of the assets.

To be clear, and in case I've missed anything simple, I'm making these changes, committing the code to GitHub, then executing `git push staging master`. My development machine is a Windows 8 machine.

**EDIT** 
Here is the output from executing `git push staging master`:

```
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 569 bytes, done.
Total 6 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle -
-binstubs vendor/bundle/bin
       Updating git://github.com/milgner/compass-rails.git
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Resolving dependencies...
       Using rake (10.1.0)
       Using i18n (0.6.4)
       Using minitest (4.7.5)
       Using multi_json (1.7.7)
       Using atomic (1.1.10)
       Using thread_safe (0.1.0)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
       Using activesupport (4.0.0)
       Using builder (3.1.4)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using rack (1.5.2)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Using actionpack (4.0.0)
       Using mime-types (1.23)
       Using polyglot (0.3.3)
       Using treetop (1.4.14)
       Using mail (2.5.4)
       Using actionmailer (4.0.0)
       Using activemodel (4.0.0)
       Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
       Using arel (4.0.0)
       Using activerecord (4.0.0)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Using chunky_png (1.2.8)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
       Using execjs (1.4.0)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Using thor (0.18.1)
       Using railties (4.0.0)
       Using coffee-rails (4.0.0)
       Using fssm (0.2.10)
       Using sass (3.2.9)
       Using compass (0.12.2)
       Using compass-rails (1.0.3) from git://github.com/milgner/compass-rails.g
it (at 1749c06)
       Using hike (1.2.3)
       Using jbuilder (1.4.2)
       Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
       Using json (1.8.0)
       Using modernizr-rails (2.6.2.3)
       Using pg (0.15.1)
       Using tilt (1.4.1)
       Using sprockets (2.10.0)
       Using sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
       Using rails (4.0.0)
       Using rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.1)
       Using rails_stdout_logging (0.0.1)
       Using rails_12factor (0.0.2)
       Using rdoc (3.12.2)
       Using sass-rails (4.0.0)
       Using sdoc (0.3.20)
       Using turbolinks (1.3.0)
       Using uglifier (2.1.2)
       Using zurb-foundation (4.0.9)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
       Removing rails_log_stdout (01b5bcc572e3)
       Removing rails3_serve_static_assets (84910ceb4ca2)
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Asset precompilation completed (13.42s)
       Cleaning assets
-----> WARNINGS:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types      -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, web, worker

-----> Compiled slug size: 37.0MB
-----> Launching... done, v16
       http://myproject.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:myproject.git
   82f4d58..e930ff1  master -> master
```

Comment: Please add log from `git push heroku`

Comment: Ok, so compilation goes on, should you really set `config.serve_static_assets = true`? It's false by default and I think should stay this way.

Comment: I've had it set both ways, no change.

Comment: I'm looking into my Rails 4 app and you should set static assets to false and have only this gem `gem 'rails_12factor'`

Comment: I reset to the default production.rb config (including `config.serve_static_assets = false`) and only included the `rails_12factor` gem from the ones I mentioned. Still not serving these files.

Comment: Aaaand in which group do you have this heroku gem? You know that assets group is not used since Rails 4?

Comment: I know, it's in the `production` group.

Comment: Just asking stupid little things because I see no other answer.

Comment: No, thanks for asking, there's a good chance it's due to one of those 'stupid little things'.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In your production config file, have you also tried setting:

```
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

The `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile` line has been removed and is not needed in Rails 4.

Also, the rails_12factor gem is set up to include the two other gems you need for heroku, so you don't have to include them in your Gemfile. You can get more info about that on their [github](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor) page.

For whatever reason, though, I always had to make sure to use the rails image_tag to get my images to display in production. Not sure if you are doing that, but it made a big difference on my app.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but nope. `config.assets.compile` was set to `false` but changing it to `true` had no effect. Ugh.

Comment: Bummer. Those two lines did the trick for me. Out of curiosity, I just noticed that you are pushing to a staging environment, not production. Did you make all the discussed changes in your staging.rb environment file?

Comment: No I didn't and I had no idea I needed one, I've been using my `production.rb`. This could definitely be the cause but I'll have to give it a go later this evening. Thanks!

Comment: And no. For what it's worth I even created a new production server and deployed there and still no change. Thanks so much for your help though!

Comment: adding config.assets.digest = true worked for me, rails 5 heroku

Comment: I read in another comment that config.assets.compile = true is bad for production.rb